# Is there a way to add multiple short answers to one question in google forms (not a quiz)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a little problem. I need to add multiple short answers by question in google forms but I don't find that alternative. Is there a way to do that? For example:

```
the form would be like:

Enter your name:

"short answer 0"

Enter the name of your 3 best friends:

"short answer 1"
"short answer 2"
"short answer 3"

the resulting data should be like:

name               friends

"short answer 0"   "short answer 1"
"short answer 0"   "short answer 2"
"short answer 0"   "short answer 3"
```

There is someone that know how to do that? Is there another tool different from google forms that allow to do that? I'll be grateful

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn’t appear to be related to programming Google Forms. Given that, it should instead be posted to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Instead, create a new section and ask the question 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, not possible. But you can get around it by adding multiple short answers but giving only the first one a question. Like here:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfsfCITS9BQkH92xEEkqf2Kb2RmOnIq-pEgUoCSBn3m7lSWlw/viewform

Or you can add custom styling to the form
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9BHCv2x_Pg